# Global shell varible resets on shell startup

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, variable, fzf

I've tried using fzf, and I've done `export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` as per the instructions. I set it to `ag -g ""`. For the rest of the session, `echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND` gives me `ag -g ""`. However, when starting the shell again, I get `rg --files --hidden` from `echo $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND`. Putting `export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND='ag -g ""'` in my .zshrc does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it, there was a command changing it in my .zshrc

Comment: That just means you had another command in the file that was setting the variant.